# Compiling gtk from sources

Tags: c, build, compilation, gtk, gtk3

I'm tring to compile `gtk+-3.2.0` but I get an error message from `./configure`:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.29.14... 
*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.32.4, but GLIB (2.34.0)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
no
configure: error: 
*** GLIB 2.29.14 or better is required. The latest version of
*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/gtk/.
```

I really have GLIB 2.34.0 (which I have compiled from sources too) but I don't know how to do gtk know the library. I have changed  PKG_CONFIG_PATH to points to path where is the new glib installation and after a `ldconfig` but makes no difference. by modifing /etc/ld.so.conf I really have no idea how to do.

Comment: Okay, so I think you have to remove an old version of GLib?

Comment: But it will not broke another source codes?

Comment: By removing older glib version can makes source code that use such version non-compilable

Comment: Probably not, as glib is quite backwards-compatible (especially with minor versions)

Comment: it depends how you installed it

Comment: Need to see what you set PKG_CONFIG_PATH and where you installed glib to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH` should contain the path to the directory where the .pc file for the GLib version you want to use is.

Otherwise, use your package manager to detect which package has installed the .pc file that you don't want to use. And remove that package. For example, on an rpm-based distro, run:

```
strace -eopen pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0 2>&1 | grep "\.pc"
```

It will return where is located the .pc file detected by pkg-config.

```
open("/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

Then detect to which package this file belongs:

```
rpm -qf /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
```

Here's the result on my Mageia 2 system:

```
lib64glib2.0-devel-2.32.4-1.1.mga2
```

Removing this package will remove the .pc that gets in the way. However, you should prefer the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` method in the case removing the package also tries to remove other dependencies you still want to use.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have fixed it yesterday,but I've forget to notice this here. Also, what the version shall 'pkg-config  --modversion gtk+-3.0` returns? I'm getting 3.2.1 and gtk-demo works fine, but when I try to compile some program I get

Comment: `/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `gdk_broadway_window_get_type'
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `gdk_x11_device_manager_xi_get_type'
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `gdk_broadway_get_last_seen_time'
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `gdk_extension_mode_get_type'
/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `gdk_x11_device_xi_get_type'`

Comment: Fixed it installing gtk 3.0.0. Thanks very much again. Just another problem: some widgets aren't well drawd; I get errors like `Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css: 817:65: Could not recognize the image file format` how to fix it?

Comment: Give a look at that file, and check at line 817 which file format it is trying to open. Then check you have a gdk-pixbuf loader for that file format.